# Page not loading even after 200 status

Tags: django

I'm trying to redirect to the invoice page but nothing changes except the refresh

this is the url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', User_login_view, name='login'),
    path('home/', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path("nglm/", NGLMView.as_view() , name="nglm"),
     """ other urls for the sidebar"""
    path("createinvoice/", NGLINVAPI.as_view(), name="createinvoice"),
    path("nglinvoice/", NGLInvoiceTV.as_view(), name="nglinvoice")
    ]
```

After login I go to "nglm" page where I input the customer details and click the submit button which calls the api "createinvoice". the class is shown below

```
class NGLINVAPI(APIView):
def post(self,request):
    if 'nglinv' == request.POST['formtype'] :
        data = {
            'name': request.data['cname'],
            'civilid': request.data['civilid'],
            'ph':request.data['ph'],
            'disc':request.data['disc'],
            'bookno':request.data['Bookno'],
            'tga':request.data['LAmount'],
        }
        p,ccreated = update_customerdb(data=data)
        l = update_gldb(data=data)
        data['cid'] = p.id
        iq,i = update_inventory(data=data,gl=l)
        lici = update_LICI(cid=p,lid=l,data=data)
        ninv = update_invoice(licid=lici,lid=l,cid=p,data=data,il = iq,items = i)
        invid = ninv.id
        NGLItemModel.objects.all().delete()
        base_url = '/nglinvoice/'
        query_string =  urlencode({'pk': ninv.pk}) 
        url = '{}?{}'.format(base_url, query_string)
        return redirect(url)    
    return HttpResponseRedirect('home')
```

this should have redirected me to invoice page "nglinvoice". the view is show below

```
class NGLInvoiceTV(TemplateView):
template_name = "pages/nglinvoice.html"
def get(self, request):
    p = request.GET['pk']
    inv = get_object_or_404(InvoiceModel, pk=p)
    context = {}
    context['segment'] = 'api'
    context['pagename'] = 'New GL API'
    context['object'] = inv
    
    return render(request,self.template_name , context)
```

I have no issues up to this point. the problem is it doesn't show the page  "nglinvoice.html", it just refresh the "nglm" page

below is what the terminal is showing:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 15, 2022 - 16:47:28
Django version 3.2.9, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[15/May/2022 16:47:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4103
[15/May/2022 16:47:55] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/May/2022 16:47:55] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23840
[15/May/2022 16:47:58] "GET /nglm/ HTTP/1.1" 200 24028
[15/May/2022 16:47:58] "GET /itemlist/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2
[15/May/2022 16:48:02] "POST /additem/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/May/2022 16:48:02] "GET /nglm/ HTTP/1.1" 200 24028
[15/May/2022 16:48:02] "GET /itemlist/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2
[15/May/2022 16:48:23] "POST /additem/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8
[15/May/2022 16:48:23] "GET /itemlist/ HTTP/1.1" 200 104
[15/May/2022 16:48:34] "GET /apicheck/?term=p HTTP/1.1" 200 17
[15/May/2022 16:48:35] "GET /get_customerdetails/?k=PETER+JOHNSON&t=n HTTP/1.1" 200 102<br>
[15/May/2022 16:48:38] "POST /createinvoice/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[15/May/2022 16:48:38] "GET /nglinvoice/?pk=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 13863
```

if I enter the last url manually, I can see the page but if i click the submit button it just refresh the page

how can i go to the invoice page after the clicking the submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this on Django Forum as well and was suggested force JavaScript to redirect instead from the APIView and it started to work

https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/page-not-loading-even-after-200-status/13777/4

So I made a few changes

In my view:

```
class NGLINVAPI(APIView):
 def post(self,request):
    if 'nglinv' == request.POST['formtype'] :
        """Blah Blah Blah """
        url = url = reverse('nglinvoice', args=(ninv.pk, ))
        return JsonResponse({'url':url},safe=False)    
    return HttpResponseRedirect('home')
```

and in my ajax success

```
        success: function (response) {
        window.location.href = response.url          
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Side note, too long for comment.

URL dispatching is done in non-Django way, in non-REST way. Why `/nglinvoice/?pk=5` ? This leads to extra "look around" code reinventing built-in django features available out of the box.

Instead of this:

```
# urls
urlpatterns = [
    path("nglinvoice/", NGLInvoiceTV.as_view(), name="nglinvoice")
    ]

# view
base_url = '/nglinvoice/'
query_string =  urlencode({'pk': ninv.pk}) 
url = '{}?{}'.format(base_url, query_string)
```

try this:

```
# urls
urlpatterns = [
    path("nglinvoice/<int:pk>/", NGLInvoiceTV.as_view(), name="nglinvoice")
    ]

# view
url = reverse('nglinvoice', args=(ninv.pk, ))
```

here is an [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#examples) from the docs specifically with *redirect*.

Instead of generic TemplateView try more specific and related to what is going on in your code [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview). It will automatically get requested record.

Comment: I did try that approach first. It was giving the same result, I also tried using detailview, listview, made a different class, function as well, still same results. I can view the page manually but not from the submit button.